# Converting NSData to NSString in Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to convert NSData to NSString..What is the best way to do this?

I am using this code but the final string returns null

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

When I see console It will print null.

Comment: @Nik.... @Marvin: Are you the same person or from within the same lan? I just wonder, why your [identicons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392280/what-is-the-algorithm-used-to-generate-those-little-gravatar-identicon-images/392288#392288) are exactly the same.

Comment: What's the string? If you're getting `nil` then I guess your data isn't a valid utf8 string?

Comment: @vikingosegundo For your kind information i don't know nik...

Comment: that is really funny, as it is extremely unlikely. but still possible.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The docs for `NSString` says

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416374-initwithdata

> Return Value An NSString object
>   initialized by converting the bytes in
>   data into Unicode characters using
>   encoding. The returned object may be
>   different from the original receiver.
>   Returns nil if the initialization
>   fails for some reason (for example if
>   data does not represent valid data for
>   encoding).

You should try other encoding to check if it solves your problem

```
 // The following constants are provided by NSString as possible string encodings.
enum {
   NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1,
   NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding = 2,
   NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding = 3,
   NSUTF8StringEncoding = 4,
   NSISOLatin1StringEncoding = 5,
   NSSymbolStringEncoding = 6,
   NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding = 7,
   NSShiftJISStringEncoding = 8,
   NSISOLatin2StringEncoding = 9,
   NSUnicodeStringEncoding = 10,
   NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding = 11,
   NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding = 12,
   NSWindowsCP1253StringEncoding = 13,
   NSWindowsCP1254StringEncoding = 14,
   NSWindowsCP1250StringEncoding = 15,
   NSISO2022JPStringEncoding = 21,
   NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding = 30,
   NSUTF16StringEncoding = NSUnicodeStringEncoding,
   NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x90000100,
   NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x94000100,
   NSUTF32StringEncoding = 0x8c000100,
   NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding = 0x98000100,
   NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding = 0x9c000100,
   NSProprietaryStringEncoding = 65536
};
```

Comment: `NSASCIIStringEncoding`

Comment: I used the numbers in lldb. Otherwise it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Note: If you are unsure of your encoding type or if it isn't always the same, this approach will be good for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691430/2057171

Answer (score 100):

Use below code.

```
NSString* myString;
myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:nsdata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: this will not give me the proper string

Comment: if not, it is not `NSASCIIStringEncoding`. see [felipes answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411965/converting-nsdata-to-nsstring-in-objective-c/6412275#6412275) for other encodings

Comment: For this encoding NSUTF8StringEncoding  giving nil

Answer (score 17):

`-[NSString initWithData:encoding]` will return `nil` if the specified encoding doesn't match the data's encoding.

Make sure your data is encoded in UTF-8 (or change NSUTF8StringEncoding to whatever encoding that's appropriate for the data).

Comment: I converted an image into the NSdata and again converting the NSdata into the String using the NSUTF8StringEncoding. But it is showing nil.

Answer (score 6):

Objective C:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:nsdata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Swift:

```
let str = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[Data bytes]];
```

Comment: This does not work as described  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:head encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] works

Answer (score 2):

`-[NSString initWithData:encoding]` is your friend but only when you use a proper encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Swift:

```
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .ascii)
```

or `.utf8` or whatever encoding appropriate

Answer (score 1):

## Unsure of data's encoding type? No problem!

Without need to know potential encoding types, in which wrong encoding types will give you nil/null, this should cover all your bases:

```
NSString *dataString = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn];
```

**Done!**

---

---

---

*Note: In the event this somehow fails, you can unpack your NSData with `NSKeyedUnarchiver` , then repack the `(id)unpacked` again via `NSKeyedArchiver`, and that NSData form should be base64 encodeable.*

```
id unpacked = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:unpacked];
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective C includes a built-in way to detect a the encoding of a string embedded in NSData.

```
NSData* data = // Assign your NSData object...

NSString* string;
NSStringEncoding encoding = [NSString stringEncodingForData:data encodingOptions:nil convertedString:&string usedLossyConversion:nil];
```

Answer (score -2):

> in objective C:

```
NSData *tmpData;
NSString *tmpString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tmpData];
NSLog(tmpString)
```

Comment: this one is wrong, it will return something like ```{length = XX, bytes = 0xYYYYYYYY}``` and I assume question was how to unwrap encoded string from raw bytes, not their description