# Converting NSData to NSString returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I know this question is asked before, but none of the solutions worked for me. I am trying to convert an `NSData` object to a `NSString` value. I am initing the `NSString` object like following:

```
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But the `html` is always `nil`. The `NSData` I am trying to convert is the source code of a website. It is fairly long. **[This](http://pastebin.com/KPxuwd2m)** is 'NSData` I am trying to convert.

Is it the length of the data that is causing the issue? I need the source code as a string. What can I do to resolve this issue?
What I tried so far:

- Tried with all encoding formats as shown in **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411965/converting-nsdata-to-nsstring-in-objective-c/6412275#6412275)** answer.
- Tried with `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[urlData bytes]];`

But whatever I do produce the same result. `html` always is `nil` whatever I do.

**EDIT**

It was a problem with the debug console. Even when the objects had values in it, the debug console always showed nil as the value for most of the objects. However NSLog always displays the value.

Comment: I would look at the `NSData` object.  Add some debugging to check length and disclose some of its content.  If these look OK, then encoding is the next suspect.

Comment: Is your data encoding is UTF8?

Comment: Are you sure the NSData object you are using is the one you are logging?  Silly question but this is the Internet so I have to ask unless you show.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. I have showed the NSData object in the pastebin link above.

Comment: I didn't see that initially.  I'd say that data looks OK, so it's a strange error.

Comment: @nicael: it is certainly UTF8, please see the content of the data from the pastebin link.

Comment: @trojanfoe It is certainly UTF8, but still I tried with all possible encoding formats. No success.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. What happens when pastebin goes down? Include all relevant data in the question itself. If you have to include 100K of text, then perhaps you need to narrow it down a bit more.

Comment: @dandan78 The `NSData` object by itself is more that 200K of text. Certainly can't include it here.

Comment: I got it almost work with the `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. Is that what you should retrieve: http://pastebin.com/qWy99EPy ?

Comment: @Larme yeah.. What did you do?

Comment: @Larme Did you use the same code as mine and got it working?

Comment: I think something is broken in your code. Can we chat?

Comment: Yeah.. But sorry.. I am not sure how to open a chat room.

Comment: I am not getting the move to chat link yet!!

Comment: How are you retrieving the data?

Comment: Using a synchronous request. `urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:mUrlRequest1
                                    returningResponse:&response
                                                error:&error];`

Comment: @HarikrishnanT http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56637/nsdata-nsstring-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem with `debugger`
The problem comes from compiler optimization, compiler see that string was not directly used, and optimizes the code by removing it and directly passing it to another method.

**The key of the problem** : You are running project on `release` scheme

**Solution:**
Here is a small guide to switch project to the `Debug` scheme

1) Click on the target, and click `Edit scheme...`

[image]

2) Popup will be displayed

[image]

3) Click `Run %Your project%`
4) Open Build Configuration popup
5) Select `Debug`
5) Press `OK`
6) You are ready to Go!, now you can debug anything :)

Comment: Hi, I will check this and say as soon as i reach office tomorrow. :)

Comment: You said it.. Thanks.. That was the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ARC, and you just wrote the code that converts the data to a string and haven't written any code yet that actually uses the string, it will get deallocated immediately. Check whether that is what is happening. For example, what does NSLog (@"%@", html) display?

Comment: Well, I am using the string right on the next line of `NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`, that is the allocating code. I tried setting a breakpoint on the line allocation(above line) and stepped into and found that the string is nil even after allocating, right in the next line of allocation. That definitely can't be ARC right?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSAttributedString *str = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]}
documentAttributes:nil error:&error];
```

Comment: Even this is returning nil

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
 NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Generally, conversion from NSData to NSString returns nil means there is mismatch between encoding format received from server and approach used for encoding.

Comment: I had already tried this one. Just tried again. Not working. As I said, I tried with ALL encoding types.

Comment: Then there might be issue from response received from server end. Try using another response.

Comment: I have already posted the `NSData` object along with the question. The response looks OK. And rather, it is the response I need to convert to string. Converting another response may work, but certainly won't help me. :)