# NSData to NSString not working (for use in QCComposition)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I have A NSdata value that it needs to be converted into a string.

So far my app works fine loading a QC composition from a server however, I have a warning when I tell QC to load data from server.

[image]

It loads the file just fine but is there a way to avoid this worming?

I have tried to convert data to string using

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

HOwever, it is giving a null location of the file

Comment: You're sure urlData is `NSData`? What do you see if you log it?

Comment: Please check your answer here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411965/converting-nsdata-to-nsstring-in-objective-c/6412275#6412275

Comment: NSString *absoluteURL = @"http://server.com/qc.qtz";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:absoluteURL];

    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    
   
    QCComposition *qc = [QCComposition compositionWithFile:urlData];

Comment: if I log it it gives me: ----  62706c69 73743030 dc000100 02000300 04000500 06000700 08000900 0a000b00 0c000d00 0e000f00 10003900 3a005100 52005306 5a0d980d 995b6465 73637269 7074696f 6e5f1016 65646974 6f725669 65776572 466f7263 65436c65 61725f10 10667261 6d65776f 726b5665 7273696f 6e5e706f 72744174 74726962 75746573 5f101265 6469746f 72566965 77657257 696e646f 775f100f 696e7075 74506172 616d6574 6572735b 61737065 63745261 74696f5d 7468756d 626e6169 6c446174 615e7669 72747561 6c506174 ….

Comment: Akhil I have checked that and tried all the option but the string is always null

Comment: Please edit the extra information into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the way I was loading the file with wrong method the correct one is:

```
QCComposition *qc = [QCComposition compositionWithData:urlData];
```