# Convert NSData to NSString and convert again to NSData?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata, nsfilemanager

I have this code who get a file inside my iOS, convert it to an NSData and converts it into a NSString:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;

filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSData *files = [filemgr contentsAtPath:databasePath];

NSData *databuffer = [filemgr contentsAtPath:databasePath];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",databuffer];
```

All I wanna know is if there is the possibility to convert this NSString to NSData and back through the NSData using NSFileManager and resave the file in its original format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411965/converting-nsdata-to-nsstring-in-objective-c

Try.

Comment: You need to explain the purpose for wanting an NSString representation.

Answer (score 1):

The `stringWithFormat` is an expensive way to call NSData's `description` method.  This simply produces a hex dump.  And, we are advised, Apple makes no guarantees that `description` methods produce a format that will not be changed in the future, so it should only be used for diagnostic purposes.

If you want to convert an NSData to string format so it can be transmitted as a string you should use Base64 encoding.  If the NSData is actually character info it should be converted to NSString using the appropriate string encoding.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an `NSData` to an `NSString` use:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
```

Assuming the data was encoded with `NSUTF8StringEncoding` (a good bet).

To convert an `NSString` to an `NSData`:

```
NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
```

Assuming the data encoding should be `NSUTF8StringEncoding` (a good bet).

You need to do some research/studying the difference between NSData and NSString.